# annoying Grails console view in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

When developing a Grail app in IntelliJ there's a console view:

[image]

Whenever I make changes to the app outside IntelliJ, this view grabs the focus and lots of building messages start appearing. This also happens on occasions when making changes within the IDE.

I would like to hide, delete, disable or remove this view if possible?

(FYI, this view has nothing to do with the Grails console that appears when you run the `grails console` command)

Comment: Did you turn off "make before launch" checkbox in run configuration? Do you run your app with Grails run configuration, not with plain Java?

Comment: make before lauch is disabled. I run my app with the maven grails plugin, so the command is "mvn grails:run-app"

Comment: This is triggered by fsnotifier, on linux this is a seperate process using kernel's inotify interface. Maybe killing this process helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable it in the current version, however this problem will be addressed in the future builds, our developers are aware of it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I don't find this all that inconvenient.  Personally, I appreciate the fact that I know IDEA is doing what it should be.  Background stuff is nice, but sometimes it is good to know things are working correctly.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Has this been fixed in Intellij 12? I can't find the option.

Comment: Did anything change?